# "what role DOES reason and emotions play (...)?" - formulated by English native speaker teacher

Tags: verb-agreement, auxiliary-verbs

The English native speaker teacher of a friend wrote the following question:

> What role does reason and emotions play in sharing knowledge?

As far as I know, this question has a grammatical error, for the subject is plural: *reason and emotions.* So it should be:

> What role do reason and emotions play in sharing knowledge?

However, I think that if his teacher had taken *reason and emotions* as one whole unit, then he could use *does* instead of *do.* I am not sure if that way of expressing the question would be idiomatic though. 
Is the usage of *does* possible in this case, or is it just a grammatical error?

Comment: There's no real precedent to group reason and emotion as one thing. In fact they are often seen as opposites. I would say this is just a common error people make.  There are two subjects, so it should be "do."  In addition, I would change it to "emotion" not "emotions."

Comment: I agree with KumaAra, above, additionally, I would change 'role' to 'roles', which underlines that 'reason' and 'emotion' are actually separate elements.

Comment: The English of the English, even teachers, is not always good.

Comment: In the context, "reason and emotions" is considered a single causative factor, so singular verb is correct in that sense. Apropos @KumaAra -- it's true they are contradictory. However, the net effect is what comes into play.

Comment: Easier cases to see the difference in agreement notional concord allows/demands are: 'Bacon and eggs are both to be found on aisle 17' / 'Bacon and eggs is my favourite meal for breakfast'. / Like KumaAra,  I wouldn't use a singular verb here.